# Installing Sitecore 9 in XP0 setup with SOLR instance on Remote Server

Tags: solr, installation, sitecore-install-framework

I have setup the sitecore 9 on my machine and used [setup guide](https://buoctrenmay.com/2017/10/30/a-step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-9-installation-on-your-machine/)

I have installed SQL Server 2017 and SOLR 6.6.2 in Remote Server.
[The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard]

I have followed the instruction for setting up the SOLR, enabled the SSL ...

In my dev machine [Windows 10], I have tried to execute install.ps1 file to install the Sitecore 9

Below is the install.ps1 file

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "sc9" 
$PSScriptRoot = "D:\sc9_install"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://sg1dev06:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "\\sg1dev06\solr-6.6.2" 
$SolrService = "Solr_6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "SG1DEV06" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword = "AtmLg69K" 

#$solrParams = @{     
#    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
#    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
#    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
#    SolrService = $SolrService     
#    CorePrefix = $prefix 
#} 

#Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    } 
 Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    }
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for sitecore $solrParams = 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"  
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
    } 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

I have got below error during the installation
[image]

Below is the Error Stack Trace for reference

```
[-------------------------------------------- StartWebsite : ManageWebsite -------------------------------------------]
[StartWebsite]:[Start] sc9.xconnect
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Start-Website" on target "sc9.xconnect".
VERBOSE: Checking state of Website 'sc9.xconnect'
VERBOSE: Starting Website 'sc9.xconnect'

[-------------------------------- ConfigureSolrSchemas [1] : ManageSolrSchema ----------------------------------------]
VERBOSE: Resolving ConfigFunction extension 'joinpath'
VERBOSE: Resolved 'Invoke-JoinPathConfigFunction'
VERBOSE: Invoke-JoinPathConfigFunction
VERBOSE: Joining: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc9.xconnect\App_Data solrcommands schema.json
VERBOSE: Result: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc9.xconnect\App_Data\solrcommands\schema.json
VERBOSE: Checking Solr instance 'https://sg1dev06:8983/solr'
VERBOSE: GET https://sg1dev06:8983/solr with 0-byte payload
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Could not find Solr instance: https://sg1dev06:8983/solr"
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Could not find Solr instance: https://sg1dev06:8983/solr"
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not find Solr instance: https://sg1dev06:8983/solr
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:55 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not find Solr instance: https://sg1dev06:8983/solr
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:55 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:02:25
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20180417184401
**********************
```

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

## Update 1

My SOLR is working fine and the certificate is valid

[image]

My SIF Version is as below

[image]

Note: I did manual SIF installation since the I got below error when I tried to install using script

[image]

Comment: the use of `sitecore-install-framework` and `xconnect` already signifies Sitecore 9. I also suggest that when a moderator helps you improve your post, you leave the edits be ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend installing already Sitecore 9 Update 1 as you have Solr 6.6.2 installed. For Sitecore 9 Initial Release (that you are trying to install) Solr 6.6.1 is supported. Take a look here -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897.

I think your biggest problem is that you have Solr on different machine than Sitecore. I haven't tried that myself by I would use subset of script on your Solr machine first to create cores and all of the other stuff and then run again another subset of your script on Sitecore machine to do the rest.

1) Script that you run on Solr server:

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "sc9" 
$PSScriptRoot = "D:\sc9_install"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://sg1dev06:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "\\sg1dev06\solr-6.6.2" 
$SolrService = "Solr_6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "SG1DEV06" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword = "AtmLg69K" 

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for sitecore $solrParams = 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
```

2) Script run on Sitecore server:

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "sc9" 
$PSScriptRoot = "D:\sc9_install"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://sg1dev06:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "\\sg1dev06\solr-6.6.2" 
$SolrService = "Solr_6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "SG1DEV06" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword = "AtmLg69K" 

#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    } 
 Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    }
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose 

#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"  
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
    } 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

Comment: Hi Peter, as suggested by some installation guide SOLR 6.6.1 has a core lock bug, so I have installed SOLR 6.6.2

Comment: @David - That is perfectly fine :) Install then also Sitecore 9 Update 1 ;) If you are starting with development, it is usually best to start with latest version of release that you are on...

Comment: Thanks a ton.. able to resolve the issue after splitting the script and run separately on SOLR Server and Sitecore Server

Comment: @David - Good to hear. Gladly

Comment: I have made a blog post from this. So if anybody interested in the future why this is happening and how to solve it take a look here http://tothecore.sk/2018/04/19/installing-sitecore-9-xp0-with-solr-on-remote-server

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that Solr is available and working at this address? https://sg1dev06:8983/solr

Also check that there are not HTTPS/SSL cert errors. SIF will fail the install if the Cert is invalid. You may need to re-install Solr if so.

You can try following my blog article here: http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/install-sitecore-9-update-1-4-simple-steps/
 and see if that helps with the setup.

I include a script that Jeremy Davis created that does all the Solr setup for you including the cert:

https://gist.github.com/jermdavis/8d8a79f680505f1074153f02f70b9105

Comment: Thanks Adam for assisting. I have checked my solr and the url is working as expected. The certificate seems valid. I have updated my question with more details.